# Using Jquery to Get Value from button which has span as well

Tags: jquery, html, button

I have below button

**HTML:**

```
<button><span>fdsfsd</span>Result<span>aasd</span></button>
```

Whether by anymeans i can get the value of Result in the above changes. I need to change this values using jquery. Please suggest whether its possible

Comment: what are you trying?

Comment: What you have tried so far? please provide the code.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your "Result" text in a span with an ID or at least class name for easier access with jQuery. But if you really don't have a choice you can try code below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var inner = $("button").html()
   
  $("button").html($(inner)[0].outerHTML+" MODIFIED TEXT "+$(inner)[2].outerHTML)
  
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button> 
      <span>fdsfsd</span>
      Result
      <span>aasd</span>
    </button>
```